# Tensorflow r1.3 estimator.DNNClassifier save and load graph

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am using the latest Tensorflow release 1.3.0 and created a DNNClassifier via:

```
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(...)
```

and trained it in python.

How can I save and reuse the graph/model in c++?
I only found tutorials to load the `tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier`, which is not what I would like to do... I know that checkpoints are saved automatically, but I would like to load the created graph to make predictions in c++, and the only file saved automatically is a `graph.pbtxt` (besides many `events.out` and `model.ckpt` filfes). Can I load that file like a `graph.pb`?